# Sorting list of addresses by nearest distance through latitude and longitude

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I have a list of addresses with latitude and longitude, I want to sort them by nearest distance to one address. Can anyone help?

Comment: so there's two parts here, firstly to get the distance for every address from your 'one address'.  Then to sort them.  Which part in particular do you need help with?  How many addresses are there in your list?  What does your code look like so far?

Comment: I want to display the list of restaurants by nearest first. There may be 10 or more addresses to sort. here is the link where I want to use: [Best of the Brunch](http://bestofthebrunch.co.uk/restaurants/swan-at-the-globe/).
I followed the document from http://mobiforge.com/design-development/geo-sorting-using-device-geolocation-to-sort-distance but failed to achieve result.

Comment: What does your code look like so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

let's say your addresses looks like this

```
{
   restaurant: 'Moe\'s la Patate'
   longitude: 12345,
   latitude: -1234
}
```

and are placed in an array named **addresses**

```
var addresses = [{
   restaurant: 'Moe\'s la Patate'
   longitude: 12345,
   latitude: -1234
},{
   restaurant: 'Mc Donalds'
   longitude: -531,
   latitude: 235
}// ...
];
```

and that your position is in the same format (I will use the **position** variable)

you could do the √(a^2 + b^2) calcul

```
var position = {
   longitude: 2231,
   latitude: -4211
}
var addressesByDistance = addresses.map(function(data){
    var distX = position.longitude - data.longitude;
    var distY = position.latitude - data.latitude;
    var distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(distX, 2) + Math.pow(distY, 2));
    return distance;
}).sort();
```

This doesnt take in consideration the round up of the earth but having only 10 restaurants, I suppose they are all in the same city?

Anyways, hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the help. I used your function to calculate the distance and added this to each element as an attribute, then applied insertion sort to sort them via distance attribute.